# ggplot2 theme to color inside of polar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `ggplot2` to make plots with polar coordinates.

I would like to set the background color inside of the circle to be a different color than the background color outside of the circle. (The reason is that I'm going to convert the plot to a raster and make the area outside the circle transparent.)

The `ggplot` `theme` attribute for `plot.background` does what I expect.  But I can't seem to find a way to make `panel.background` only paint inside the plot. There's no `element_circle` analog for `element_rect`.

Can anyone advise?

Here's a minimally reproducible example:

```
data.frame(
  x = rnorm(1000), 
  spoke = factor(sample(1:6, 1000, replace=T))
) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = spoke, fill=spoke, y = x)) +
  geom_violin() +
  coord_polar() +
  theme(
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "darkblue"),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightblue",
                                    colour = "lightblue"))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a hacky way: make a dummy data frame of the minimum and maximum values at each of the factor levels, then use it to draw bars filling up that space. Setting `width = 1` with polar coordinates would be used to make a pie chart—here it does the same thing, but you aren't distinguishing between pie wedges.

You probably don't actually want to work with the exact maximum of `x`; it would make sense to add some amount of padding as you see fit, but this should be a start.

If you were working with data that had a minimum at 0 or somewhere above it, you wouldn't need to repeat the data like I did—that was the best way I could figure out to get bars stacking from 0 to the maximum, which is positive, and from 0 to the minimum, which is negative. `geom_rect` initially seemed like it made more sense, but I couldn't get it to stretch all the way around to close the circle.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(1000), 
  spoke = factor(sample(1:6, 1000, replace=T))
)
bkgnd_df <- data.frame(spoke = factor(rep(1:6, 2)), 
                      x = c(rep(min(df$x), 6), rep(max(df$x), 6)))

bkgnd_df
#>    spoke         x
#> 1      1 -3.396064
#> 2      2 -3.396064
#> 3      3 -3.396064
#> 4      4 -3.396064
#> 5      5 -3.396064
#> 6      6 -3.396064
#> 7      1  3.195901
#> 8      2  3.195901
#> 9      3  3.195901
#> 10     4  3.195901
#> 11     5  3.195901
#> 12     6  3.195901

ggplot(df, aes(x = spoke, y = x)) +
  geom_col(data = bkgnd_df, width = 1, fill = "skyblue") +
  geom_violin(aes(fill = spoke)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "x")
```

[image]

Also worth noting that `ggforce` has a [`geom_circle`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggforce/vignettes/Visual_Guide.html), but I don't know how it would work with polar coordinates.

Comment: Haven't tried, but my guess is your `geom_col` method will work much better than using `geom_circle`.

Comment: Hey thanks - this is right, and I'm accepting the answer.  But you don't need to have two rows for each spoke. One row with the max value for each spoke is sufficient.

Comment: If all the values in the violins were positive, that would be true. But the bars will start at 0, so only having the max value leaves an unshaded circle for the negative values. If your real data is only positive, that doesn't matter, although you still might want to scale to fit between the min and max.